# INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't exists error while creating EntityManager (JPA + SPRING + H2)

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-mvc, h2, information-schema

I have a problem with JPA (OpenJPA) + Spring (Web Flow using Spring Web MVC) + H2 database engine. I've got simple RegisterDAO for my simple web application. I am using dependency injection to inject EntityManagerFactory (by @PersistentUnit annotation) to my RegisterDAO. Everything looks ok (EntityManagerFactory is not null, it seems to be injected) but problem occurs when I'm trying to create EntityManager from this factory. GlassFish (which i use) throw an exception something like this (can't print in original, because message is in Polish :)):

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'register' of flow 'register'
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:569)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:788)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Schema 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' doesn't exists {SELECT SEQUENCE_SCHEMA, SEQUENCE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES} [code=-1, state=42Y07]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:556)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:456)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.java:101)
    at umk.dumont.db.dao.RegisterDAO.checkIfLoginIsFree(RegisterDAO.java:156)
    at umk.dumont.services.RegisterService.validateForm(RegisterService.java:95)
    at umk.dumont.models.RegisterFormModel.validateRegister(RegisterFormModel.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:186)
    at org.springframework.webflow.validation.ValidationHelper.invokeValidateMethodForCurrentState(ValidationHelper.java:122)
    at org.springframework.webflow.validation.ValidationHelper.invokeModelValidationMethod(ValidationHelper.java:109)
    at org.springframework.webflow.validation.ValidationHelper.validate(ValidationHelper.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.validate(AbstractMvcView.java:625)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.processUserEvent(AbstractMvcView.java:217)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:248)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:218)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Schema 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' doesn't exists {SELECT SEQUENCE_SCHEMA, SEQUENCE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES} [code=-1, state=42Y07]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:273)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:253)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:70)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:305)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:186)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:175)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.prepareStatement(DBDictionary.java:5131)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.getSequences(DBDictionary.java:3942)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaGenerator.generateSequences(SchemaGenerator.java:960)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaGenerator.generateSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:365)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaGenerator.generateSchemas(SchemaGenerator.java:300)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.getDBSchemaGroup(SchemaTool.java:1142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.add(SchemaTool.java:348)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.run(SchemaTool.java:325)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:504)
    ... 61 more
```

This is strange, because when I use H2 Console and type "SELECT SEQUENCE_SCHEMA, SEQUENCE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES" everything is ok (I see this set of tables named INFORMATION_SCHEMA). Of course I call this sql statement logged in username which I use in my persistence.xml file.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
My configs:
persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
  <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:F:\baza"/>
  <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>
  <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="haslodobazy"/>
  <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Tool=INFO"/>
  <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

applicationCotext.xml for spring:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="myPersistenceUnit"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean id="registerDaoImpl" class="umk.dumont.db.dao.RegisterDAO" />

<bean id="service" class="umk.dumont.services.RegisterService">
    <property name="registerDAO" ref="registerDaoImpl"/>
</bean>
<bean class="umk.dumont.models.RegisterFormModel">
    <property name="service" ref="service"/>
</bean>
```

web config:

```
<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>myPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>persistenceUnitNameFromPersistenceXML</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>
```

I use maven, my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.150</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually using Apache Derby and not H2. Reason: there is no such error message or code within H2. However, Apache Derby uses exactly this message and code when running this statement.

Could you please check the configuration? Somewhere you are using `jdbc:derby:...` instead of `jdbc:h2:...`

Comment: At first thanks for your reply. Generally it is possible that I have done something wrong in config files, because I had a lot of troubles to set up my db with spring. But I have checked my configs and only when I use "jdbc:" prefix is persistence.xml. I will post my configs above.

Comment: I suggest to grep for `jdbc:derby:`, and if you find nothing, grep for `derby`

Comment: There is no strings contains "derby" in my project :( I will try with mysql database a bit later and post what happend. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I have changed db and other strange problem with sql statement occurs (couldn't create table, but statement looks fine - I've checked it). I'm going back to H2, because I think this is problem with my spring config - not with H2.